# bucketAuto and lookup in Aggregation Framework (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections one for online people and the other one for players with an account.
I am trying to find how many players with account are online.
Positive identification occurs within 3 matching fields (last_name or email or first name or mobile phone)
I am using a bucketAuto approach. The code goes by

```
{
  from: "players",
  let: {
    last_name: "$last_name",
    email: "$email",
    first_name: "$first_name",
    mobile: "$mobile",      
  },
  pipeline: [
  {
      $bucketAuto:
       {groupBy:{
                "$size": {
                "$setIntersection": [
                  [
                    "$$last_name",
                    "$$email",
                    "$$first_name",
                    "$$mobile"
                  ],
                  [
                    "$last_name",
                    "$email",
                    "$first_name",
                    "$mobile"
                  ],
                ]},
            },          
         buckets:5           
    }
  }    
  ],
  'as': "matches",
}

#This is the model of the resulting output:

matches
0 Object
_id Object
count
5043

1 Object
_id
Object
count
4
```

I understand the 5043 represents all the mismatches of a document and 4 is the number of matches of the targeted documents.

My intention was to get something like:

```
matches
0 Object
_id 0
count
5043

1 Object
_id 1
count
1

2 Object
_id 2
count
3

3 Object
_id 3
count
0

4 Object
_id 4
count
4
```

The group _id should be number of intersections in bucketAuto stage with its respective counter.

```
Sample data:
{
  "last_name": "Hansen",
  "first_name": "Dawn",
  "email": "hdawn@email.com",
  "mobile": "+352000900"
}
```

The desired output I've already expressed saying "My intention was to get something like..."

Comment: Can you add some sample data, along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is basically comparing every document on one collection with every document on the other collection, so considering the efficiency and according to your purpose, I suggest to start the pipeline with a `$match` step. Then we can continue the intersection test, but we are only interested on documents with 3 matching fields or more, and for each one, only the best match is relevant:

```
db.online.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "players",
      let: {
        last_name: "$last_name",
        email: "$email",
        first_name: "$first_name",
        mobile: "$mobile"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$or: [
                {$eq: ["$email", "$$email"]},
                {$eq: ["$mobile","$$mobile"]}
        ]}}},
        {$project: {
            _id: 0,
            matchFieldsCount: {
              $size: {$setIntersection: [
                  [
                    "$$last_name",
                    "$$email",
                    "$$first_name",
                    "$$mobile"
                  ],
                  [
                    "$last_name",
                    "$email",
                    "$first_name",
                    "$mobile"
                  ]
              ]}
            }
        }},
        {$match: {matchFieldsCount: {$gte: 3}}},
        {$sort: {matchFieldsCount: -1}},
        {$limit: 1}
      ],
      as: "matches"
  }},
  {$set: {matches: {$first: "$matches"}}},
  {$bucketAuto: {groupBy: "$matches.matchFieldsCount", buckets: 3}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2H9WsrNmTE1)